# ionic v1 open pdf using inappbrowser and pdf.js

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

i am trying to open pdf in ionic-v1 app.
I want to keep all pdfs on server and parse it will pdf.js file.
pdf.js will be at server ( not in mobile app). pdf.js uses <>.html file to show pdf file.

I want to use inappbrowser to open this server html file and show pdf.
Will this work?  Please help.

Answer (score 3):

1) Install cordova inappbrowser plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

2) Open pdf in inappbrowser:

```
function openMyPDF(){
   let pdfUrl = 
   encodeURI("https://ionicframework.com/files/Ionic2Migration.pdf");
   var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(pdfUrl, "_blank);
}
```

Note : encodeURI() on this if the URL contains Unicode characters. encodeURI really helpful.

Comment: I will recommend open pdf in default pdf opener. That give best user experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
install plugin

cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
then try this

<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
  Open pdf
       </a>
```

Comment: i don't want to use mobile pdf software